# Why does this binding doesn't work through XAML but does by code?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, static, properties

I am trying to bind to a static property on a static class,
this property contains settings that are deserialized from a file.

It never works with the following XAML :

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="wrapper" ObjectType="{x:Type Application:Wrapper}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource wrapper}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

   <ComboBox x:Name="comboboxThemes"
                  SelectedIndex="0"
                  SelectionChanged="ComboBoxThemesSelectionChanged"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.Row="8"
                  Margin="4,3" ItemsSource="{Binding Settings.Themes, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedValue="{Binding Settings.LastTheme, Mode=TwoWay}"   />
```

It does work by code however :

```
comboboxThemes.ItemsSource = Settings.Themes;
```

Any idea ?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answers !

It did silently throw an *Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation* i didn't know more ...

I was initializing a log that writes to a file; the designer finally showed up the details of the exception, it was looking for creating the file in Visual Studio directory which is in Program Files, hence a security exception was thrown.

Apparently VS copies the file to its folder, for its Designer.

I fixed it like this :

```
 var isInDesignMode = DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(SettingsWindow);
        if (!isInDesignMode)
        {
            Log = new WrapperLogManager("log_wrapper.txt");
        }
```

Last but not least, using ObjectDataProvider never worked as well, only through x:Static

This was driving me totally crazy for a few days as it's not so hard to bind data; I just learned another lesson !

Comment: Also, I have design-time preview now as well !

Answer (score 5):

Your code-behind doesn't perform a binding, it directly assigns a source to the `ComboBox`...

If you want to do the same in XAML, you don't need a binding at all, you just need the `StaticExtension` markup extension :

```
ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Settings.Themes}"
```

(where `local` is the xmlns mapping for the namespace containing the `Settings` class)

Answer (score 2):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StaticTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:StaticTest="clr-namespace:StaticTest"
    Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Static StaticTest:MyStaticStuff.MyProp}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace StaticTest
{
    public static class MyStaticStuff
    {
        public static string MyProp { get { return "From static"; } }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ItemsSource you can use a direct x:Static assignment as shown in the other answers but for the SelectedValue you need a Binding, which requires an instance on which to set a property. You should be able to restructure the static class into a Singleton to provide a bindable instance and property which can still be referenced statically from code, something like:

```
public class Settings : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static Settings Instance { get; private set; }

    public static IEnumerable<string> Themes { get; set; }

    private string _lastTheme;
    public string LastTheme
    {
        get { return _lastTheme; }
        set
        {
            if (_lastTheme == value)
                return;
            _lastTheme = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastTheme"));
        }
    }

    static Settings()
    {
        Themes = new ObservableCollection<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
        Instance = new Settings();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then the ComboBox would use these bindings:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Settings.Themes}"
SelectedValue="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Instance}, Path=LastTheme}"   />
```

Comment: Thank you all, I've tried everything you said, it doesn't work; in fact I did try that route already.
When I create a small test project, it works fine; for odd reasons on this one it doesn't and it's too huge so I can post the code; I think I am going to rewrite this whole part.
What I've found however is an "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" occurs through IntelliSense/Resharper, i don't know really as I am unable to debug furthermore this step.

Thank you,